# Why is dinitrogen tetraoxide less stable at high temperature?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry

I have calculated the enthalpy of dimerisation for the reaction at low temperature:

$$\ce{2NO2 <=> N2O4}$$
$$\Delta_\mathrm{dimerisation}\ce{H}= \pu{-13.87 kcal mol^{-1}}= \pu{-58.03  kJ mol^{-1}}$$

Also for this reaction, $\ce{\Delta S}$ is negative due to presence of more gaseous moles on LHS.

My book mentions that $\ce{N2O4}$ is stable only at low temperature. Why is it so? I couldn't find any reliable sources on the internet.

Comment: By Le Chatelier's principle, exothermic reactions tend to shift their equilibrium position to the reactants when the temperature is increased.

Comment: Enthalpy should be given in $\pu{kJ/mol}$ or $\pu{kcal/mol}$ if you must use those outdated nonstandard units. This doesn’t matter here but your answer does not work if you ignore the mol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out the answer using [Van't Hoff Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_%27t_Hoff_equation):
$$\ln\left(\frac{\ce{K_2}}{\ce{K_1}}\right)=-\frac{\ce{\Delta H}}{\ce{R}}\left({\frac{1}{\ce{T_2}}-\frac{1}{\ce{T_1}}}\right)$$

Let's assume that $\ce{\Delta H}$ is constant for a limited range of temperature.

Since $\ce{\Delta H}$ is negative for the reaction $(=\pu{-13.87 kcal mol^{-1}})$ if we increase the temperature i.e. $\ce{T_2>T_1} \to\ce{K_1> K_2}$. Thus, equilibrium shifts towards the left as the temperature increases implying the decreasing stability of $\ce{N2O4}$ with increasing temperature.